# Modulo arithmetic question

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm reading Eulers criterion for quadratic residues, and have found his formula:

if a number a is a quadratic residue than $a^{(p-1)/2} = 1$.

But I am reading through the examples in Wikipedia, and I am not understanding a step they are doing, it is this:

"In one case, testing p = 3, we have $$17^{(3 − 1)/2} = 17^1 \equiv 2 \equiv −1 \pmod 3$$, therefore $17$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$."

How are they going from $2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$?

Comment: Are you asking why is $2$ congruent to $-1$ modulo $3$?

Comment: I think you meant $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Well first $17 \equiv 2 \pmod {3}$ because $3 \space  \mid \space 17 - 2 = 15$

Now by the same reasoning. $2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$ because $3 \mid 2 - (-1) = 3$

and so $17 \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$ which you can also verify because $3 \mid 17 -(-1) = 18$

You should remember that the definition of congruence.

$a\equiv b \pmod{m} \iff m \mid  a-b$

And you also notice that it's transitive that is if $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ and $b \equiv c \pmod {m}$ then $a \equiv c \pmod{m}$